# JS window.open() causes HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: javascript, html

So I have these 2 files (plus 1 more [second.html] for the second page). The problem is that when I click on the button it does open the second.html in a new tab but the initial tab comes up with the error:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

But I want the initial page (home.html) to stay loaded

home.html

```
<body id="id_body">
    <input type="button" value="Button" onclick="this_but()" >
    <script src="home.js"></script>
</body>
```

home.js

```
function this_but(){
    location.href = window.open("second.html");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Assigning a new value to `location.href` and using `window.open()` are completely different things and don't work together this way Get rid of   `location.href =`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use :-

`window.location.href = "second.html";` or `location.href = "second.html";`

and if you want to open in new window then  `window.open("second.html");`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the:
`location.href`?

```
function this_but(){
    window.open("second.html");
}
```

See this example:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open

Answer (score 1):

Remove `location.href =`.

```
function this_but() {
  window.open("second.html");
}
```

**The problem was:**

You were setting the first tabs' `location.href` (URL in the address bar) to an object (`window.open`). An object is not a URL, so the first tab came up with a 404 (URL Not Found) error.

You can see the invalid URL in your screenshot:

[image: The URL is an object]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the location.href. Simply use window.open("second.html"); For further reading, check out (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp). You can use following code:

```js
    function this_but(){
    window.open("second.html");
}
```